# Querydsl - Split results into two or more objects

Tags: java, sql, orm, kotlin, querydsl

I have a query that's returning a list of objects (say `Employee`), and I'd like to append the total, unpaged `count(*)` of the results along side it. Something like:

```
+---+-------------------+-------------+------------+
|   |     id            |      age    |    total   |
+---+-------------------+-------------+------------+
| 1 | 1234              | 24          |12          |
| 2 | 154367            | 61          |12          |
| 3 | 9485048386        | 36          |12          |
+---+-------------------+-------------+------------+
```

Which I would get from emulating a query like:

```
SELECT * , COUNT(*) OVER() AS total
FROM employee
LIMIT 3
OFFSET 0
```

How can I query for this type of data and retrieve a `List<Employee>` and a singular `Long` for the `total`? Currently, I have this going, but I'm uncertain how to expand it for the new `total` column/value:

```
projection = Projections.constructor(Employee.class, qEmployee.id, qEmployee.age);
select(projection).from(qEmployee).where(foobar).offset(0).limit(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this by adding the `SQLExpression` needed for the window function to the `select(...)`. The query now returns a `List<Tuple>` where the first element of the Tuple is my `Employee` object, and the second is the `total`:

```
projection = Projections.constructor(Employee.class, qEmployee.id, qEmployee.age);
List<Tuple> results = select(projection, SQLExpressions.count().over()).from(qEmployee).where(foobar).offset(0).limit(3);
```